# Как сконструировать правильную архитектуру Thread для Rx?

Tags: java, многопоточность, rxjava

Изучаю RxJava.
Есть в `main` rx конструкция:

```
ProcessFactory.generateProcessing(5)
                .flatMap(processes -> Observable.from(processes))
                .flatMap(process -> Observable.just(process))
                .doOnNext(process -> {
                    process.start();
                })
                .subscribe(process -> System.out.println(process.toString() + " subscribed"));
```

Метод генерирует список тредов обернутых в Observable:

```
public static Observable<List<Process>> generateProcessing(int count) {
        Random rand = new Random(71);
        int bound = 5;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            mProcessList.add(Process.newProcess("Process" + i, rand.nextInt(bound)));

        return Observable.just(mProcessList);
    }
```

Сам класс `Process` простой и унаследован от `Thread`, все что он делает - это некоторое время работает и генерирует некоторые данные:

```
public class Process extends Thread {

    private String name;
    private int duration;
    private int[] myArray;

    private Process(String name, int duration) {
        this.name = name;
        this.duration = duration;
        Logger.log("Process %s create. d = " + duration, name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Logger.log("Process %s start! d = " + duration + " sec", name);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(duration * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myArray = downloadBytes();
        Logger.log("Precess %s finish", name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    private int[] downloadBytes() {
        int bound = 100;
        Random rand = new Random(31);

        return new int[] {rand.nextInt(bound),
                rand.nextInt(bound),
                rand.nextInt(bound),
                rand.nextInt(bound)};
    }

    public int[] getData() {
        return myArray;
    }

    public static Process newProcess(String name, int duration) {
        return new Process(name, duration);
    }
}
```

Как можно сделать так, что бы после выполнения своей задачи можно было сразу уведомлять об этом `Subscriber` и в моем случае, например, вывести данные на консоль?

Comment: вы пытаетесь использовать rx не правильно, ниже в ответе все правильно расписали, что в фоне можно запустить выполнение, указав лишь шедулер нужный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В rx уже есть все что нужно для работы с многопоточностью. Вот небольшой пример подобный Вашему. Класс, в котором выполняется работа:

```
class Process {
int id;

public Process(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

void work() {
    try {
        System.out.println("running process " + id + " in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("process finish " + id + " in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

И методы для выполнения работы в разных потоках

```
public static Observable<String> runProcessObs(int id) {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
        new Process(id).work();
        return "Notify sucess " + id; //здесь возвращаем сообщение после того как работа выполнена. Можно возвращать напрямую из метода "work()" и можно возвращать объекты любого типа (предварительно указанного в дженерике)
    })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()); //каждый Process подписываем на отдельный поток
}

public static void runProcesses() {
    Observable.range(0, 5)
            .flatMap(integer -> runProcessObs(integer))
            .subscribe(System.out::println); 
}
```

логи:

```
09:00:32.479  I/System.out: running process 0 in thread RxIoScheduler-3
09:00:32.479  I/System.out: running process 1 in thread RxIoScheduler-2
09:00:32.480  I/System.out: running process 2 in thread RxIoScheduler-5
09:00:32.480  I/System.out: running process 3 in thread RxIoScheduler-6
09:00:32.481  I/System.out: running process 4 in thread RxIoScheduler-4
09:00:33.479  I/System.out: process finish 0 in thread RxIoScheduler-3
09:00:33.479  I/System.out: Notify sucess 0
09:00:33.480  I/System.out: process finish 1 in thread RxIoScheduler-2
09:00:33.480  I/System.out: Notify sucess 1
09:00:33.481  I/System.out: process finish 2 in thread RxIoScheduler-5
09:00:33.481  I/System.out: Notify sucess 2
09:00:33.481  I/System.out: process finish 3 in thread RxIoScheduler-6
09:00:33.481  I/System.out: Notify sucess 3
09:00:33.481  I/System.out: process finish 4 in thread RxIoScheduler-4
09:00:33.481  I/System.out: Notify sucess 4
```

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ!